# How do we set OS X Lion sync to show warning before data on computer is changed?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization

In the past we used to have to go to iSync preferences but iSync has been completely removed in OS X Lion. Any ideas?

I would personally prefer a warning before **any** data is changed on my computer, on account of issues such as Snow Leopard used to "support" Google Contacts sync but would remove all nicknames from your contacts.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have your snapshot backup of your OSX Snow Leopard before you upgraded to Lion (you did backup didn't you?), then there is a solution to getting iSync back up and working under Lion :

[slashusr.wordpress.com](http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/the-missing-isync-in-os-x-lion-and-what-to-do-about-it/)

Extract follows :

> Before installation of Lion, I had taken a full disk image of my
>   previous Snow Leopard installation using the excellent SuperDuper!
>   Disk cloner.
>
> This was more from a backup and recovery perspective, but allowed me
>   an unexpected solution to the iSync quandary – on a whim, I attached
>   the Snow Leopard disk to the Mac running Lion, and clicked on the
>   iSync application. Voila! iSync works exactly as it should!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is set sync to manual mode.

It is expected that some sync operations will delete data. I don't know of a good publish/subscribe solution, so just be sure to watch and have good, regular backups.